# How to load complex web logs syntax with Pig?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am a complete beginner on Pig. I have installed cdh4 pig and I am connected to a cdh4 cluster. We need to process these web log files that are going to be massive (the files are already being loaded to HDFS). Unfortunately the log syntax is quite involved (not a typical comma delimited file). A restriction is I cannot currently pre-process the log files with some other tool because they are just too huge and can't afford storing a copy.  Here is a raw line in the logs:

> "2013-07-02 16:17:12
>   -0700","?c=Thing.Render&d={%22renderType%22:%22Primary%22,%22renderSource%22:%22Folio%22,%22things%22:[{%22itemId%22:%225442f624492068b7ce7e2dd59339ef35%22,%22userItemId%22:%22873ef2080b337b57896390c9f747db4d%22,%22listId%22:%22bf5bbeaa8eae459a83fb9e2ceb99930d%22,%22ownerId%22:%222a4034e6b2e800c3ff2f128fa4f1b387%22}],%22redirectId%22:%22tgvm%22,%22sourceId%22:%226da6f959-8309-4387-84c6-a5ddc10c22dd%22,%22valid%22:false,%22pageLoadId%22:%224ada55ef-4ea9-4642-ada5-d053c45c00a4%22,%22clientTime%22:%222013-07-02T23:18:07.243Z%22,%22clientTimeZone%22:5,%22process%22:%22ml.mobileweb.fb%22,%22c%22:%22Thing.Render%22}","http://m.someurl.com/listthing/5442f624492068b7ce7e2dd59339ef35?rdrId=tgvm&userItemId=873ef2080b337b57896390c9f747db4d&fmlrdr=t&itemId=5442f624492068b7ce7e2dd59339ef35&subListId=bf5bbeaa8eae459a83fb9e2ceb99930d&puid=2a4034e6b2e800c3ff2f128fa4f1b387&mlrdr=t","Mozilla/5.0
>   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Mobile/10B329
>   [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/6.2;FBBV/228172;FBDV/iPhone4,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone
>   OS;FBSV/6.1.3;FBSS/2;
>   FBCR/Sprint;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/1]","10.nn.nn.nnn","nn.nn.nn.nn,
>   nn.nn.0.20"

As you probably noticed there is some json embedded there but it is url encoded. After url decoding (can Pig do url decoding?) here is how the json looks:

> {"renderType":"Primary","renderSource":"Folio","things":[{"itemId":"5442f624492068b7ce7e2dd59339ef35","userItemId":"873ef2080b337b57896390c9f747db4d","listId":"bf5bbeaa8eae459a83fb9e2ceb99930d","ownerId":"2a4034e6b2e800c3ff2f128fa4f1b387"}],"redirectId":"tgvm","sourceId":"6da6f959-8309-4387-84c6-a5ddc10c22dd","valid":false,"pageLoadId":"4ada55ef-4ea9-4642-ada5-d053c45c00a4","clientTime":"2013-07-02T23:18:07.243Z","clientTimeZone":5,"process":"ml.mobileweb.fb","c":"Thing.Render"}

I need to extract the different fields in the json and the "things" field which is in fact a collection. I also need to extract the other query string values in the log. Can Pig directly deal with this kind of source data and if so could you be so kind to guide me through how to have Pig be able to parse and load it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such complicated task, you ususally need to write your Load function. 
I recommend [Chapter 11. Writing Load and Store Functions](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/load_and_store_funcs.html) in **Programming Pig**. [Load/Store Functions](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual#Load.2FStore_Functions-1) in official docuemnt is too simple.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented plenty and learned tons. Tried a couple json libraries, piggybank and the java.net.URLDecoder. Even tried the CSVExcelStorage. I registered the libraries and was able to solve the problem partially. When I ran the tests against a larger data set, it started hitting encoding issues in some lines of the source data resulting in exceptions and job failure. So I ended up using Pig's built-in regex functionality to extract the desired values:

```
A = load '/var/log/live/collector_2013-07-02-0145.log' using TextLoader();
-- fix some of the encoding issues
A = foreach A GENERATE REPLACE($0,'\\\\"','"'); 
-- super basic url-decode
A = foreach A GENERATE REPLACE($0,'%22','"');

-- extract each of the fields from the embedded json
A = foreach A GENERATE 
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"redirectId":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as redirectId, 
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"fromUserId":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as fromUserId, 
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"userId":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as userId, 
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"listId":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as listId, 
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"c":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as eventType,
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"renderSource":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as renderSource,
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"renderType":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as renderType,
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"engageType":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as engageType,
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"clientTime":"([^"\\}]+).*$',1) as clientTime,
    REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'^.*"clientTimeZone":([^,\\}]+).*$',1) as clientTimeZone;
```

I decided not to use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in case the order of the fields varies.

Comment: Encoding is annoying. But TextLoader and PigStorage do not provide a way to set the encoding.